# How can I programmatically find the content types handled by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-type

Within a Google Chrome extension, I would like to be able to programmatically obtain a list of all of the HTTP `Content-Type`s that it can handle. For example, some of the ones it handles are `text/plain`, `text/html` and `application/pdf`.

Comment: Why do you want to know which Content-Types are recognized by Chrome?

Comment: @RobW, unfortunately, I've actually forgotten exactly why I wanted to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the MIME Types mapping in chrome

```
static const MimeInfo primary_mappings[] = {
  { "text/html", "html,htm" },
  { "text/css", "css" },
  { "text/xml", "xml" },
  { "image/gif", "gif" },
  { "image/jpeg", "jpeg,jpg" },
  { "image/webp", "webp" },
  { "image/png", "png" },
  { "video/mp4", "mp4,m4v" },
  { "audio/x-m4a", "m4a" },
  { "audio/mp3", "mp3" },
  { "video/ogg", "ogv,ogm" },
  { "audio/ogg", "ogg,oga,opus" },
  { "video/webm", "webm" },
  { "audio/webm", "webm" },
  { "audio/wav", "wav" },
  { "application/xhtml+xml", "xhtml,xht" },
  { "application/x-chrome-extension", "crx" },
  { "multipart/related", "mhtml,mht" }
};

static const MimeInfo secondary_mappings[] = {
  { "application/octet-stream", "exe,com,bin" },
  { "application/gzip", "gz" },
  { "application/pdf", "pdf" },
  { "application/postscript", "ps,eps,ai" },
  { "application/javascript", "js" },
  { "application/font-woff", "woff" },
  { "image/bmp", "bmp" },
  { "image/x-icon", "ico" },
  { "image/vnd.microsoft.icon", "ico" },
  { "image/jpeg", "jfif,pjpeg,pjp" },
  { "image/tiff", "tiff,tif" },
  { "image/x-xbitmap", "xbm" },
  { "image/svg+xml", "svg,svgz" },
  { "message/rfc822", "eml" },
  { "text/plain", "txt,text" },
  { "text/html", "shtml,ehtml" },
  { "application/rss+xml", "rss" },
  { "application/rdf+xml", "rdf" },
  { "text/xml", "xsl,xbl" },
  { "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml", "xul" },
  { "application/x-shockwave-flash", "swf,swl" },
  { "application/pkcs7-mime", "p7m,p7c,p7z" },
  { "application/pkcs7-signature", "p7s" }
};
```

For further lookup and you can see the reference

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/mime_util.cc

---

#### EDIT 1:

Yes there is no direct access for this data in chrome extension API

But you can build MIME sniffer class in javascript and feed it with supported Mime Types then when user about to download file you can test the content against the supported types.

This is Unit test of in the source code.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/mime_sniffer_unittest.cc

---

Generally All the browsers has support for the standard MIME types

http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full

http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: +1 You're on the right track, though the list is slightly bigger. I've researched this a few weeks ago for a (not yet published) Chrome extension, and it turns out that most relevant info can be found in mime_util.cc. Also, all text files are "supported", with the exception of those listed in `unsupported_text_types`.

Comment: Thanks; looking at the MIME-related source files is helpful. However, this doesn't provide programmatic access to the information. I consider this information dynamic (rather than static) because either new formats could be introduced and standardised in the future, and because I think installing a plug-in could add support for additional `Content-Type`s such as various video file formats.